# ASP.NET Core Angular site stopped sometimes hosted in IIS

Tags: c#, angular, windows, asp.net-core, iis

I developed asp.net core/Angular application and hosted in IIS. But it was stopped several times with unknown reason.

How Can I find the reason for it and get it sorted?. I checked the event viewer and I am not able to find any considerable reasons in there.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are making a HTTP connection to the IIS.  Are you getting a response?  If not,  The connection is failing due to TLS encryption failing due to encryption mode not being supported on IIS.  Seen this a lot.  Only way for sure is to use a sniffer and verify the the HTTP message was sent.  TLS is performed before the HTTP Request is sent and if TLS fails you will never see the HTTP request.  If request is sent than you need to see the status code in the response to determine failure.

Comment: "But it was stopped several times", then in which way? You need to describe clearly what you observed and how it stopped. Error pages, error messages, and any useful information should be included in the question.

Comment: does the website work sometimes?

Comment: Vague descriptions alone do not allow community members to understand the problem you are experiencing.  I don’t understand what you mean by being stopped multiple times for unknown reasons? Did you get an error page when accessing the application page? Have you checked the IIS logs?

Comment: I think you need to check the IIS logs first. These logs can provide valuable information about requests and errors that may cause the application to stop. Log files path: `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\logs\LogFiles`.
You can enable detailed errors in IIS's Error Pages module, which can help you get more information about the error that caused your application to stop.
Also, check the applicationpool's timeout configuration and recycling settings.